# Clojure Parameters with Optional Flags

Tags: clojure, parameters, keyword

What's the best way to implement keywords as optional flags to a function?
I want to make function calls such as:

```
(myfunction 5)
(myfunction 6 :do-this)
(myfunction 3 :go-here)
(myfunction 2 :do-this :do-that)
```

Using defn, I can define a function such as:

```
(defn myfunction [value & flags] ... )
```

But the `flags` becomes a list. I can write my own function to search the list, but such a function isn't included in the core library, so I assume it's not idiomatic.

What I'm using now:

```
(defn flag-set? [list flag] (not (empty? (filter #(= flag %) list))))
(defn flag-add [list flag] (cons flag list))
(defn flag-remove [list flag] (filter #(not= flag %) list))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lists (as well as vectors and maps) are not a good choice of data structure for value-based lookups (will be linear time), that's why clojure.core doesn't have such functions.

Sets do provide fast value-based lookups via "contains?", so how about

```
(defn foo [value & flags]
  (let [flags (set flags)]
    (if (contains? flags :add-one)
      (inc value)
      value)))
```

If there won't be more than one flag, you can use destructuring like this:

```
(defn foo [value & [flag]] …)
```

Comment: Ah, Sets provide contains?. In that case I'll probably just use what I have but change the code for flag-set? to use (contains? (set flags) flag).

Comment: You can abbreviate (contains? flags :add-one) as (flags :add-one) or (:add-one flags).

Comment: If you want linear search for lists and vectors, it's in clojure.contrib.seq-utils/find-first.  If your list is only a few items long it may be faster to do a linear search than to cast it into a set.  Most of the time you're probably going to be passing only a small handful of parameters to your functions.

Comment: The "lookup time" argument only makes sense if you have several flags to check, since `(set flags)` is already a linear operations. In any case if the lookup time starts to matter maybe a set or a map of flags instead of a varargs list should be used in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

`clojure.contrib.def` includes the `defnk`-macro, which makes defining functions with keyword-arguments easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can use hash-map binding for [destructuring](http://clojure.org/special_forms#Special%20Forms--Binding%20Forms%20%28Destructuring%29) of optional parameters like this:

```clj
(defn myfunction 
  [value & {:keys [go-there do-this do-that times] :or {times 1}}]
  {:pre [(integer? times) (< 0 times)]}
  (println "Saw a" value)
  (when go-there
    (dotimes [n times]
      (when do-this (println "Did THIS with" value))
      (when do-that (println "Did THAT with" value)))))
```

The above function may be called the following way:

```
(myfunction "foo" :go-there true :do-this true :do-that false :times 5)
```

Notice that you can define default values for keys with the `:or {times 1}` clause. The following function call will only loop once due to that default:

```
(myfunction "foo" :go-there true :do-this true :do-that false)
```

Also, Clojure's [precondition expressions](http://clojure.org/special_forms#toc9) allow for convenient testing of parameters, which applies to the values of the destructured keys too, as it can be seen in the `{:pre [...]}` expression right after the parameter bindings. The following call will fail due that precondition check:

```
(myfunction "foo" :go-there true :do-this true :do-that false :times -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

this is strictly speaking not the most efficient way of writing this but it's clear

```
(defn myfunction [value & flags] 
  (cond (contains? (set flags) :a) 1
        (contains? (set flags) :b) 2)
```

it could be more efficient to factor (set flags) up.

Answer (score 0):

Converting the rest argument list into a set just to check for membership can be considered clumsy. Using `some` with a static set for that purpose is considered idiomatic though. So you could do something like this

```clj
(defn myfunction [value & flags]
  (if (some #{:do-this} flags)
    [value flags]))

(myfunction 123 :do-this)
-> [123 (:do-this)]
```

An alternative could be using [keyword arguments](https://clojure.org/reference/special_forms#keyword-arguments) which were introduced in Clojure 1.2. E.g.

```clj
(defn myfunction [value & {:keys [do-this]}]
  (if do-this
    [value do-this]))

(myfunction 123 :do-this true)
-> [123 true]
```

This adds the "burden" to the caller to provide an explicit `true` value for the flag, but the function signature becomes arguably less obscure and self-documenting (since a name like `flags` is rather abstract). So I suppose it's a tradeoff.